# Loop through Names and insert rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

On first inspection this sounds really easy - it probably is for the majority of you, however I have been using VBA for little under a week and thought I had perfected the google technique - how wrong I was...

I have a list of player names next to which are their captains (therefore every team has a list of players and the captain is repeated down as is the team name)

I am hoping to write some code that will automatically read through and upon the captains/teams name changing insert two rows

Unfortunately my current attempts have been unsuccessful with using a loop as I end up creating a new row after every row.

Any help is much appreciated :)

```
Sub InsertRows()
Dim TM As String
Dim TM2 As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

TM = ws.Cells(2, "B").Value
TM2 = TM
i = 3
Do
    TM = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    If TM <> TM2 Then
    EntireRow.Insert
    EntireRow.Insert
    Else
    i = i + 1
    TM2 = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    If TM = "" Then Exit Do

End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show what you have so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: @skyline75489 I have taken a deeper look and now my loop won't work either - hopefully the code will make it more obvious

Comment: Check your last `Loop` and `End If`. I think the positions might be swapped.

Comment: @Jeeped It no longer bugs now - and I removed the ItRng stuff :) But still doesn't insert the rows :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should do this:

```
Do
    TM = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    If TM <> TM2 Then
        ws.Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Insert
        ws.Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Insert
        i = i + 2
    End If
    TM2 = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
    i = i + 1
Loop Until ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ""
```

1. After you insert the new rows you need to update `i` with the statement `i = i + 2` for it to indicate the correct row and not the newly inserted one.
2. The next row should be processed and `i` should be incremented whether it's a new TM or not.

Answer (score 0):

Even without code to see I bet you can solve this by traveling up the list instead of down.

```
For intA = 10 to 1 step -1 
' ...
```

Next